# img tag with svg image is not working properly with html2canvas and jsPDF (React)

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

Like the title says whenever I have an img tag with svg image the pdf is missing that image, but If it's for example .png or .jpg it is working as intended, here is my code:

```
function App() {
  function handleDownloadPdf() {
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName("outer_container")[0];
    html2canvas(element, { useCORS: true, allowTaint: true }).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
      const pdf = new jsPDF(
        "p",
        "px",
        [element.clientWidth, element.clientHeight],
        true
      );
      const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
      const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, "", "FAST");
      pdf.save("chart.pdf");
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleDownloadPdf}>Download as PDF</button>
      <div className="outer_container">
        <div className="container">
          <img src={Bosnia} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is how the component looks like:
[image]

And this is how the pdf document looks like:
[image]

Does anyone know what is the issue is it with html2canvas not capturing svg images or is it with jsPDF not being able to convert svg elements to pdf?